# Операционная система для изучения Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Программирую на c#, подрабатываю на asp.net (3курс), но в долю сложившихся тенденций, решил изучить ruby, так как в основном ориентируюсь на веб.
Веб для руби это Ruby on Rails. Вопрос в том какую лучше операционною систему использовать для программирования на рельсах, на Windows можно, но как в книге было описано что лучше не надо, а вот выбор между Ubuntu или Mac OS X (хакинтош так как у меня не мак) или же принципиально нет разницы в обучении и практике для рельс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я начинал изучать Rails на машине с Windows7. Не всё было гладко, но с некоторой долей гугления можно зайти достаточно далеко. Так что если Windows привычнее - можно не отказываться от него. Ну или можно поставить VMware Player и установить виртуальную ubuntu.

Comment: это не гугл а книга о рельсах "Подробное руководство по созданию приложений в среде Ruby on Rails" Оби Фернандес  
цитата "Необходимое технологическое обеспечение : Последняя модель apple macbookpro с 4г памяти и операционной системой os x 10.4. Шучу конечно.Linux тоже вполне годиться для разработки в Rails. MS Windows ? Cкажу так - у вас может быть другое мнение.В этой книге мы НЕ БУДЕМ обсуждать разработку для rails на платформе microsoft"  
Просто пробежался по вакансиям везде необходим unix experience,при том что основный скринкасты и видио по руби с конф в основном на маке

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, для веб-программинга очень желательно иметь основные навыки работы с никсами. Так что welcome

Comment: всем спасибо кстати за ответы.   

"очень желательно иметь основные навыки работы с никсами"
это же вроде веб сервер для рельс, он типа только под  unix?

Comment: ну так веб и никсы - близнецы-братья.

Comment: Кстати в качестве виртуальной машины могу также порекомендовать VirtualBox. Постоянно пользуюсь и очень доволен.

Comment: Ясно спасибо. так и думал в принципе 
VirtualBox + Ubuntu 11.10 + RubyMine 4(или Aptana)

Answer (score 2):

Говорю на собственном опыте.
Начинал пробовать rails на windows. Для начальных этапов можно попробовать, но по мере усложнения проекта начинают возникать проблемы.

Для нормальной работы с изображениями нужно приложение ImageMagick, и гем RMagick, однако за долгое время гугления, я так и не смог поставить рмэджик, правда нашел замену - 'mini magick'. В общем, для работы с изображениями на Windows, придется колхозить.

Далее) чтобы создавать массив изображений, нужна база данных postgresql, потому что sqlite не поддерживает массивы:

```
t.string   "images",    default: [],   array: true
```

Найти нормальные уроки по работе с postgresql и rails на windows тоже достаточно трудно. В то время как на linux все занимает буквально пару секунд.

Вся крутая тусовка создает ништяки на unix системах, и при попытке качнуть с гитхаба какую-нибудь современную тему, постоянно вылазят ошибки, которые порой и не решить.

И по мере усложнения своих проектов, Вы начнете использовать node.js и npm  вместе со своим rails проектом, тут опять же Вам придется делать выбор, либо постоянно решать ошибки на винде, либо делать все быстро на linux)

Поэтому, советую всем не терять время, и поставить второй системой ubuntu, и спокойно работать).

Answer (score 1):

Любая *nix система подойдёт для разработки на рельсах. На винде тоже можно, но я не пробывал. http://railsinstaller.org/ - вам сюда

Answer (score 1):

Unixlinux в первую очередь нужны для сборки GEM`ов (ruby библиотек), на Windows что-то может не заработать. Если привыкли к Windows, достаточно поставить виртуальную машину linux, freebsd, solaris (все, что нравится), научится собирать пакеты (apt-get install или pkg_add), ну и поднять samba, чтобы с виртуальной OS можно было работать как с сетевой папкой.

MacOS как правило используют из за связки "unix + приятный интерфейс + большое количество удобного софта".

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нравиться или нужна по работе винда,то используйте её. Между хакинтош и убунту,однозначно убунту,будет меньше проблем,а если и будут сообщество поможет!
 У меня была схожая проблема,я оставил винду,но поставил убунту 2й системой,сейчас это делается очень просто,почти всё автоматически. Советую и вам так поступить.

Answer (score 0):

Изучаю RoR в cloud9. Облачность позволяет не заморачиваться с настройкой окружения для изучения. Зарегался, создал окружение и пошел пробовать.